# Eclipse/C++ Configuration Issue

Tags: eclipse

I am trying to configure Eclipse/Helios on a Win7/64 Professional with CDT and MinGW. When I try and compile:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std ;

int main() {
  cout << "What a lovely day\n" ;
  return(0) ;
}
```

I get the output/error:

```
make all 
Building file: ../SeeProgram.cpp
Invoking: Cross G++ Compiler
C:\Tools\MinGW\bin\g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"SeeProgram.d" -MT"SeeProgram.d" -o"SeeProgram.o" "../SeeProgram.cpp"
/bin/sh: C:ToolsMinGWbing++: command not found
make: *** [SeeProgram.o] Error 127 .
```

In the next-to-last line, it should have read C:\Tools\MinGW\bin\g++, but it left out the back-slashes. I have not seen any other discussion of this, and have tried numerous approaches, but I am stumped at the moment. Any thoughts?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried escaping the backslashes when you enter the location, e.g.:

```
C:\\Tools\\MingGW\\bin\\g++
```

This setup seems similar to yours, maybe it could provide a hint:

http://max.berger.name/howto/cdt/ar01s03.jsp#wincompiler